# Using custom tableViewCells created in an xib in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, interface-builder

I am trying to create a custom tableview cell in interface builder and use it in a tableview created in swift, the relevant code in the controller holding the tableview is as fallows:

```
class SearchesMainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var contentTableView: UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "Search"
        self.contentTableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SingleSearchTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: SingleSearchTableViewCellController.reuseID())
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SingleSearchTableViewCellController.reuseID(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as SingleSearchTableViewCellController
        return cell
    }
```

The Cell itself is very simple, 4 labels and a custom class:

class SingleSearchTableViewCellController : UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var dateMonthLable : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var dateDayLable : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var yearLable : UILabel?
@IBOutlet var makeModelLable : UILabel?

var search : Search

class func reuseID() -> String{
    return "SingleSearchTableViewCellType"
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    search = Search()
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    search = Search()
    super.init()
}

init(previousSearch s : Search){
    search = s
    super.init()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    search = Search()
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

If I did not put enough data please feel free to ask and I thank you for your help in advance. Info on swift interacting with xib does not seem to be widely available yet.

**EDIT**
I have removed my custom class and the bindings for my cell look like this:
[image]
after making these changes the error reads as fallows:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dateDayLable.'

now it looks like it is trying to bind my views to some view that is not my customUITableViewCellController

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Generally you should design your cell directly in the tableView and reference it with its reuseIdentifier. Is there a reason the Xib can't be directly dragged onto your tableView for easier access and management? Otherwise the view can be designed in a Xib and accessed similarly to what you already posted unless there is some issue with the results.

Comment: I am looking to use this cell in multiple tableviews in my app so to design my cell directly in the tableView in interface builder would make a ton of copy paste code that I am trying to avoid

Comment: Your code worked for me when I tried it. Because I didn't do anything with Search, I commented out all the code in the cell class except for the class method. You might try that, and see if it fixes the crash.

Comment: Even after commenting out search and all references to it Im getting the same error. Maybe it has to do with my bindings in interface builder I will add those to the discription of the issue

Comment: You should leave your custom class, and in the xib file change the class of the cell to your custom class. Leave the File's Owner as NSObject. Connect the outlets from the cell to the labels.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into these kinds of issues it usually is caused by two things.  One is that the main `view` in the xib file is a `UIView` instead of a `UITableViewCell`.  The other is that the custom class field isn't being set to your custom class.

Comment: Good suggestions thank you, however I checked both and the main view is a UITableviewCell and the "File's owner" custom class is set to SingleSearchTableViewCellController

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your "Datasource" and "Delegate" connections.
2. Check that you have added  to viewController.
3. Check that you have properly assigned "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier".

Comment: Thanks again for the sugestion but the datasource and delegate have been set on the tableview, I am not sure what you mean by number 2, and as far as I can tell in the code above i have used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier correctaly

Comment: I mean that you also need to add "datasource" and "delegate" to view controller like this either in .m or .h file. @interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: I also think that if this is not the case, this means your initialization of labels is wrong. You must assign some optional value to them, if you are not giving any input to them. Else paste your all code clearly.